# Is it possible to create (and save) a fluid app with multiple tabs?

Tags: fluid.app

I use [Fluid](http://fluidapp.com/) to make webapps that I want open all the time function more like independant native apps, so they're not lost in a tab in my browser.

And Fluid allows for tabbed browsing, so I can choose to open another tab for a link, say, if I don't want to open it in my main (non-fluid) browser:

[image]

But I can't find any way to *save* multiple tabs as the Fluid App's home page, like you can on any web browser.  I want the app to automaticially open two tabs, so one fluid app can be for chat, but have a tab for two different chat rooms, one for Trello, but with tabs for a couple of boards, etc.

Am I missing some way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Developer of Fluid here. Although there's no explicit support for this, it can sorta be accomplished by:

1. Launch your Fluid App and set up the windows and tabs you would like to appear on launch.
2. Ensure that the following preference is *enabled*:

   Preferences > Behavior > On startup restore windows and tabs from last time
3. Quit and relaunch your Fluid App, and you'll see the same windows and tabs are open.

Comment: you'll just need to remember to set the tabs up like you want each time you quit.

Comment: Todd, that's a great workaround for my needs.  And not much makes me love a product more than when I see its devs actively responding to questions on our sites - thanks a ton.

Comment: My new Fluid app defaulted to a whitelist, and would open the new URL I wanted in an external browser until I added it to this whitelist.

Comment: The Behavior option seems to be missing. Is this no longer possible?

Answer (score 1):

So obviously a bit late here, but I found a workaround for those that really want this.  You will need access to a HTTP server (it may work with file:// urls, but I have not checked).

What you will do is create a HTML file that spawns tabs with the windows you want to launch, then closes itself.

Steps:

- Add your domain to the whitelist tab, as well as the domains of the sites you want to open.
- In the Security tab, uncheck "Block pop-ups"
- Add a file on your server with the following content.  In my case, I used it to open multiple Slack windows (yes I know they support multiple accounts, but this was better for me):

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      window.open('https://a.slack.com', 'a');
      window.open('https://b.slack.com', 'b');
      window.close();
  </script>
  <p>Loading Slack...</p>
  ```
- Link to that file as your startup page.